Vercel caching times and region configuration
I'm looking for advice on how caching works on Vercel and how to properly configure regions for caching.
My fetch requests are cached, and subsequent calls HIT the cache without making requests to the backend. On the localhost, these calls take about 1 ms, but on Vercel, they take 60-80 ms. This isn't much faster than fetching the data directly from the backend.
We are talking about SSR times, not client.
I understand it's an async function, but it genuinely feels like pulling the cache from Vercel is taking this time. Am I doing something wrong?
I also noticed that functions default to running in the USA while I'm in Europe. I set the regions configuration in the Vercel config to France but didn't notice any difference.
Can anyone provide insight into this behavior and what should I do before going into production?
Thanks!

Some vague expressions make it hard to infer your meaning. Could you provide more information about the following?

Where did you check the "SSR times" exactly, if not from the client?
If "60-80ms" isn't fast enough, what are your expectations? For instance, what is the minimum acceptable speed?
What is the range of response times from the backend?
Have you tried changing cache configurations other than the region value such as s-maxage?  Also providing the cache config code would be helpful for other devs to check.
What is the Next.js version you’re using?


By default, Vercel deploys functions to the US East region. Define the desired regions in your vercel.json.

On top of what brandonwie said, don't expect Vercel times to ever come close to localhost.

I checked the documentation of Vercel and here are some advices (founded here https://vercel.com/docs/infrastructure/data-cache#vercel-data-cache and here https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/regions#vercel-edge-network-regions):

Latency in Vercel Data Cache: Vercel’s Data Cache is designed to
store responses from fetch requests, but each region where your
serverless or edge function runs has its independent cache. The
latency difference you’re noticing might be due to the time taken to fetch data from the cache
layer or the regional edge infrastructure setup. This can include the
routing through Points of Presence (PoPs) and communication with the
nearest edge region for compute tasks.
Setting Regions for Functions: By default, Vercel's serverless
functions run in the iad1 (Washington, D.C., USA) region, which could
explain the slower response times if you're in Europe. You can
specify a region closer to your data or user base using the regions
configuration.
Using Edge Middleware and Network: The Vercel Edge Network leverages
PoPs to route user requests to the nearest compute-enabled edge
region. While these PoPs minimize the initial latency for requests,
the actual compute or cache retrieval may still depend on the
selected edge region. If the database or backend server is far from
the chosen region, additional latency might occur​.
Cache Configuration: Set a revalidate interval to ensure cached data
remains fresh and minimizes origin fetches. Ideally, place your edge
region close to your backend or database to avoid cascading latencies
Testing and Optimization: Before production, thoroughly test
configurations using Vercel's vercel dev CLI tool to mimic the
deployment environment and verify region-specific performance.
Consider whether Edge or Serverless runtimes better suit your use
case.

